# Customizing Bugzilla 4.0.2 Bug ID numbers

Tags: bugzilla

Is it possible to customize Bugzilla bug numbers and add a letter designator, to immediately know it came from Bugzilla?

My company is evaluating Bugzilla and has now added many new bugs. We also use 2 other bug databases. This wasn't my decision and I believe they were trying to incorporate better reporting, etc.

I read an answer here about "seeding" Bugzilla bug numbers, by setting the "AUTO_INCREMENT" field in the "bugs" table to a different value. I wish I would've thought about this sooner and found this board. Setting that value to start at 9000 or some extraordinary value would have ensured that we knew exactly which bugs came from Bugzilla.

However, would it be possible to change the field in the "bugs" table to accept letters, as well? Of course that would probably just mess up the whole auto incrementing of the numbers.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a trivial matter to do what you're asking.

However, you can still change the "seed" value for the Bugzilla database if you want. Export the existing bugs to xml, then create a new Bugzilla database. Change the seed. Then re-import the bugs. They will now all use the large bug number.

Comment: Wayne, thank you. If I did not want to change all ID numbers and have only the new bugs begin with the new numbering, could I simply change the "AUTO_INCREMENT" value and leave all the old bugs with their numbers and have only the new bugs being with the new numbers? Also, do you know of any webpages or information to point me to that might show me how to export and re-import the bugs?

Comment: All you need to do is search for all bugs then choose the XML button in the footer. Bugzilla will then send you all the bugs in XML format. Save the XML file somewhere. Then recreate the database and run importxml.pl. http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/importxml.html